# Setting up multiple DACs on an STM32F4-Nucleo

Tags: stm32, dac, data-acquisition

I am working on a project that **requires** me to use 5 TLC7524 DACs. They will all be receiving data from an 8 bit bus. For data transfer, the process is CS pin, WR pin, send Data. I was wondering if I could get away with grounding the CS pin on all of them and control them with just the WR pin.

Link to datasheet for TLC7524 -
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas061d/slas061d.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual way is select the `DAC` by `/CS` and the `/WR` signal is common for all of them.
In this way, you can connect it on `FMC` and create the `/CS` for each chip from the address (`FMC` is available on Nucleo144 boards, but not on Nucleo64 ones).

Also selected chips may have much higher current consumption (as they are active). For example `SRAM` chips are using much more current when enabled by `/CS`.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding, make a common bus for the `/WR` and then use `/CS` for selection? I am using a Nucleo64 board

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that I need each of these devices to have independent outputs, so would your way cause any issues with that?

Comment: @J.Clam Yes, common /WR and separate /CS for each DAC. Only the selected DAC will load the value on /WR signal all others are ignoring it.